# Nginx + Cloudflare. Работает www.somedomain.spb.ru, но не работает somedomain.spb.ru

Tags: nginx, https, vds, cloudflare

Достаточно трудная для меня проблема. Не могу ее пока решить самостоятельно. Все делал [по инструкциям](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-a-website-using-cloudflare-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04-ru). В файлах cert.pem, key.pem валидные ключи. Проверял инструкциями:

```
openssl rsa -check -in private.key -noout
openssl req -in /etc/ssl/cert.pem -text -noout
```

Настройки домена в Nginx тоже, один в один.

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name stb.spb.ru www.stb.spb.ru;
return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

# SSL configuration

listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.pem;
#ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/cloudfare.crt;
#ssl_verify_client on;

server_name stb.spb.ru www.stb.spb.ru;

root /var/www/stb.spb.ru/html;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}
```

На cloudflare настроены следующие DNS records:

```
А stb.spb.ru 84.38.183.29
CNAME www stb.spb.ru
```

Есть два подозрения, либо что не хватает нужного record для домена без www, либо генератор ключа cloudflare не совсем корректно генерирует сертификат для домена с поддоменом *.spb.ru

Comment: А что не работает? Какая ошибка?

Comment: Заработал. обратил вниание на такую закономерность, что если, вдруг, в вкадке с DNS появляются какие-то alert-ы, то перестает работать, предлагая отредактировать тот или иной dns. В последний раз ругался на dns TXT типа, который он ранее предлагал создать, я его просто пересоздал.
TXT stb.spb.ru v=spf1 ip4:84.38.183.29 include:stb.spb.ru include:www.stb.spb.ru ~all. Боюсь что он снова всплывет. Я так и не понял в чемм была проблема.

Comment: txt записи никакого влияния на http не имеют